# Initialize parameters as zeros in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I tried to implement parameter initialization and got the error message:

```
import numpy as np

def initialize_with_zeros(dim):
    w = np.zeros(dim, 1)
    b = 0
    return w, b

dim = 2
initialize_with_zeros(dim)
```

---

**Here is the Error:**

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         5 
>         6 dim = 2
>   ----> 7 initialize_with_zeros(dim)
>
> in initialize_with_zeros(dim)
>         1 def initialize_with_zeros(dim):
>   ----> 2     w = np.zeros(dim, 1)
>         3     b = 0
>         4     return w, b
>         5
>
> TypeError: data type not understood

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[np.zeros](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) takes only the shape as a tuple or a single integer (in case of 1-d arrays). If you just need a 1 dimensional array, pass a single parameter. If you need a 2d-array, pass as a tuple (dim,1). Hence, depending on what you want, **either use**

```
w = np.zeros(dim)
```

which will give you a one dimensional array of zeros

**or use**

```
w = np.zeros((dim, 1))
```

which will give you a two dimensional array with `dim` number of rows and 1 column.

From the [official docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html)

> numpy.zeros(shape, dtype=float, order='C')
>
> Parameters:
> shape : int or tuple of ints Shape of the new array, e.g., (2, 3) or 2.

Answer (score 0):

## Initializing parameters with zeros:

```
# GRADED FUNCTION: initialize_with_zeros
import numpy as np

def initialize_with_zeros(dim):
    w = np.zeros([dim, 1])
    b = 0
    return w, b

dim = 2
w,b=initialize_with_zeros(dim)

print ("w = " + str(w))
print ("b = " + str(b))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Also, w.r.t. to the [official documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) `numpy.zeros(shape, dtype=float, order='C')` and in relation to the existing and [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53979005/5698098) from Sheldore it'd be interesting to understand why you're using `[dim, 1]` instead of `(dim, 1)` and what the difference is? Please edit your answer to explain how your answer is an improvement over the already existing one.